# Class Y behaves like which well-known data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am doing some preparation for the exam, where I came to this question.

Class Y behaves like which well-known data structure?

[possible answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0WXy.png)

Class Y:

[Class Y code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2SQr.jpg)

I think the answer is a priority Queue. If we look at the insert method, we see when hi == A.length the variable hi is being set to 0. Eg: next time we insert a element again, it will get replaced by the new one and it will keep adding +1 to the hi variable, until hi == A.length and it "restarts" again.

Comment: Please don't post text as images.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Queue, but don't confuse a Queue with a priority Queue ! A priority Queue is a more complex structure. Instead of working as a First In First Out, it sorts the values at the insert time and outputs the min or max value contained in the structure.

You are correct however.